# Starting intent from onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I am trying to start a new activity from a custom onclick listener. But its unable to access MainActivity instance from onclick listener. Also, its showing wrong constructor for intent. Here is my code:

```
public class ChartClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private String ChartLink;
    public ChartClickListener(String chartLink){
        this.ChartLink=chartLink;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ChartImageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("chartLink", ChartLink);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: the first parameter of the intent constructor, is a context object

Comment: pass context to the constructor and use that to startactivity

Comment: post your logcat info

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Modify your code as:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),ChartImageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("chartLink", ChartLink);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

try like this

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),ChartImageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("chartLink", ChartLink);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);//Changed Here
    }
```

Hope It will work

Comment: this wont work because, MainActivity.this is not in the scope of the onclick listener class

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, not the answer that was marked as correct.

Answer (score 4):

pass activity context to custom onclick listener and use that context to startactivity

```
 public class ChartClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private String ChartLink;
    Context c;
    public ChartClickListener(String chartLink,Context context){
        this.ChartLink=chartLink;
        this.c=context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent=new Intent(c,ChartImageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("chartLink", ChartLink);
        c.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

set setOnClickListener as

```
ChartClickListener chartclicklistener=new ChartClickListener("chartLink",MainActivity.this);
b.setOnClickListener(chartclicklistener);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `MainActivity.this` with `view.getContext()` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I try this and it work, i want to show a Toast, and then transfer to a new Activity.

```
public class NumbersClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Open the list of Numbers",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.numbers:
            Intent i  = new Intent(view.getContext(), NumberActivity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.family:
            Intent   i2  = new Intent(view.getContext(),FamilyActivity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(i2);
            break;
        case R.id.colors:
            Intent  i3  = new Intent(view.getContext(),ColorsActivity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(i3);
            break;
        case R.id.phrases:
            Intent  i4  = new Intent(view.getContext(),PhrasesActivity.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(i4);
            break;

    }

}
```

}