# Activity - Intent sent info to MainActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem to recovery the data of the MainActivity from activity2.

The activity2 has this code:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    Button btnAcepta, btnCancela;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        //Listener del botó Acepta
        btnAcepta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAcepta);

        btnAcepta.setOnClickListener(

                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        // Recuperem info dels spinner

                        Spinner spiCicle=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spiCicle);
                        String txtSpiCicle = spiCicle.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        Spinner spiCurs=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spiCurs);
                        String txtSpiCurs = spiCurs.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        //Omplim un "intent" amb les dades a passar a l'altre activitat
                        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

                        //Creem un "bundle" per afegir dades extra a l'"intent"
                        Bundle extras = new Bundle();

                        // Afegim Cicle i Curs

                        extras.putString("Cicle", txtSpiCicle);
                        extras.putString("Curs", txtSpiCurs);
                        //extras.putInt("Opcio", )

                        // Afegim bundle amb la info a l'intent
                        i.putExtras(extras);

                        //Cridem l'activitat
                        startActivity(i);

                        finish();

                    }
                }
        );
```

An the IDE shows and error message at line:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

I do not understand because I want to send the info to the MainActivity.

Please Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting intent from onclicklistener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464100/starting-intent-from-onclicklistener)

Comment: This is rather about basic java knowledge than intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the proper `context` in the intent `i` since `this` refers to the anonymous class for you click listener. Change the following line:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```

to this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity2.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: This is correct but now in the main activity I can not recovery the intent information. Any idea?

Comment: The solution is with setResult(RESULT_OK, i);

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: That should be the case when you started the activity with `startActivityForResult()`...you should mention these in your question though.